# Disabling All Keyboard Shortcuts Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, compiz, shortcut-keys, scripts

Hey I want to lock down Ubuntu so that it only has access to chrome and the ability to logout.  Is there a way to get rid of all keyboard shortcuts?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could just turn off all the ones you don't use in system settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the same topic, and here's what I have done.

1. Prevent <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> from interrupting boot scripts: edit `/etc/profile` and add `stty intr undef` on the top;
2. Disable all shortcuts based on your Desktop Manager;
3. Disable kernel shortcuts:

```
echo "number" >/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

0 - disable sysrq completely;

1 - enable all functions of sysrq;